# getting spaces while writing a text fileusing file operation in c

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to write some data into the file line by line and then reading  each data separatly line by line from the source file and writing it to another file.
But while writing data to destination file , I am getting spaces.
I mean the data is being written after multiple spaces.

I am using fgets instead of fread.

```
/*
 *  ======== fatsd.c ========
 */
#include <file.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <third_party/fatfs/ffcio.h>

#include <ti/display/Display.h>
#include <ti/drivers/GPIO.h>
#include <ti/drivers/SDFatFS.h>
#include <ti/drivers/UART.h>

/* Example/Board Header files */
#include "Board.h"

/* Buffer size used for the file copy process */
#ifndef CPY_BUFF_SIZE
#define CPY_BUFF_SIZE       2048
#endif


/* String conversion macro */
#define STR_(n)             #n
#define STR(n)              STR_(n)

/* Drive number used for FatFs */
#define DRIVE_NUM           0
int i= 20;
int x;

char con_buff[100];
const char inputfile[] = "fat:"STR(DRIVE_NUM)":input1.txt";
const char outputfile[] = "fat:"STR(DRIVE_NUM)":output.txt";
const char copyfile[] = "fat:"STR(DRIVE_NUM)":copy2.txt";


 char textarray[] = "Jan 1 2017 00:00:00 75 822 96 548 85 76 82 93 78 82 64 89";
 char text[]="ram  sham heloo bye";
 char cpy[]="\r\n";


static Display_Handle display;

/* File name prefix for this filesystem for use with TI C RTS */
char fatfsPrefix[] = "fat";

//unsigned char cpy_buff[CPY_BUFF_SIZE + 1];
char cpy_buff[CPY_BUFF_SIZE + 1];
char mybuff[CPY_BUFF_SIZE + 1];

/*
 *  ======== mainThread ========
 *  Thread to perform a file copy
 *
 *  Thread tries to open an existing file inputfile[]. If the file doesn't
 *  exist, create one and write some known content into it.
 *  The contents of the inputfile[] are then copied to an output file
 *  outputfile[]. Once completed, the contents of the output file are
 *  printed onto the system console (stdout).
 */

void *mainThread(void *arg0)
{
    SDFatFS_Handle sdfatfsHandle;

    /* Variables for the CIO functions */
    FILE *src, *dst,*new;

    /* Variables to keep track of the file copy progress */
   unsigned int bytesRead = 0;
   unsigned int bytesWritten = 0;
   unsigned int filesize;
   unsigned int totalBytesCopied = 0;




    /* Call driver init functions */
    GPIO_init();

    SDFatFS_init();

    /* Configure the LED pin */
    GPIO_setConfig(Board_GPIO_LED0, GPIO_CFG_OUT_STD | GPIO_CFG_OUT_LOW);

    /* add_device() should be called once and is used for all media types */
    add_device(fatfsPrefix, _MSA, ffcio_open, ffcio_close, ffcio_read,
        ffcio_write, ffcio_lseek, ffcio_unlink, ffcio_rename);



    /* Turn on user LED */
    GPIO_write(Board_GPIO_LED0, Board_GPIO_LED_ON);



strcpy(con_buff,"This example requires a FAT filesystem on the SD card.\r\n"
        "You will get errors if your SD card is not formatted with a filesystem.\r\n");
        puts(con_buff);
    /* Mount and register the SD Card */
    sdfatfsHandle = SDFatFS_open(Board_SDFatFS0, DRIVE_NUM);
    if (sdfatfsHandle == NULL)
    {

        strcpy(con_buff,"Error starting the SD card\n");
        puts(con_buff);
        x=1;
        while (1);
    }

    else
    {

        strcpy(con_buff,"Drive  is mounted\n");
        x=2;
    }

    /* Try to open the source file */
    src = fopen(inputfile, "a");

    if (!src)
    {

        strcpy(con_buff,"Creating a new file ...");
        puts(con_buff);
        x=3;

        /* Open file for both reading and writing */
        src = fopen(inputfile, "w+");
        if (!src)
        {

          strcpy(con_buff,"Error:could not be created.\nPlease check the  Board.html if additional jumpers are necessary.check if sd card is inserted  correctly\n"
                  "Aborting... \n");
          puts(con_buff);
            x=4;
            while (1);
        }


        x=5;


        /* Reset the internal file pointer */
        rewind(src);


    }

    else {

        fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
        filesize = ftell(src);

            if(filesize!=0)
            {
                fwrite(cpy, 1, strlen(cpy), src);
            }
         fwrite(textarray, 1, strlen(textarray), src);
       fwrite(cpy, 1, strlen(cpy), src);
      fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), src);
       fwrite(cpy, 1, strlen(cpy), src);
       fwrite(textarray, 1, strlen(textarray), src);
       fwrite(cpy, 1, strlen(cpy), src);
       fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), src);

       x=6;
}

    fflush(src);
    fclose(src);


    /* Create a new file object for the file copy */
    dst = fopen(outputfile, "w");
    new = fopen(copyfile, "a");
    src = fopen(inputfile, "r");
    if(!new)
    {
        strcpy(con_buff,"Error opening new file ");
        puts(con_buff);
    }
    if (!dst)
    {

        strcpy(con_buff,"Error opening \"%s\"\n"
                "Aborting...\n");
        puts(con_buff);
        x=7;
        while (1);
    }
    else {

        strcpy(con_buff,"Starting file copy\n");
        puts(con_buff);
        x=8;
    }

    /*  Copy the contents from the src to the dst */
  while (!feof(src))
  {
      fgets(cpy_buff,sizeof(cpy_buff),src);    //READ FROM FILE
        /*  Read from source file */

        puts(cpy_buff);
        i=i+1;
       fwrite(cpy_buff, 1,sizeof(cpy_buff),dst);    //PUBLISH
       strcpy(cpy_buff,"\0");



    }

    fflush(dst);

     /* Get the filesize of the source file */
    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(src);
    sprintf(con_buff,"size of file is %d",filesize);
    puts(con_buff);



    /* Close both inputfile[] and outputfile[] */
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(new);



    sprintf(con_buff,"File \"%s\" (%u B) copied to \"%s\" (Wrote %u B)\n",inputfile, filesize, outputfile, totalBytesCopied);
    puts(con_buff);
    /* Now output the outputfile[] contents onto the console */




    /* Stopping the SDCard */
    SDFatFS_close(sdfatfsHandle);

    sprintf(con_buff,"Drive %u unmounted\n", DRIVE_NUM);
    puts(con_buff);
    return (NULL);
}

/*
 *  ======== fatfs_getFatTime ========
 */
int32_t fatfs_getFatTime(void)
{
    /*
     *  FatFs uses this API to get the current time in FatTime format.  User's
     *  must implement this function based on their system's timekeeping
     *  mechanism.  See FatFs documentation for details on FatTime format.
     */
    /* Jan 1 2017 00:00:00 */
    return (0x4A210000);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a lot of code here, much of which is likely unrelated to the problem. Can you remove code to show a [mcve] that clearly illustrates the question you have?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post a sample of what output you expect and what output you are getting.

Comment: It is not clear from your description what the actual issue is, but

    `fwrite(cpy_buff, 1,sizeof(cpy_buff),dst);    //PUBLISH` 

looks suspicious.  

It will write exactly `sizeof(cpy_buff)` bytes, but `cpy_buf` will contain a much shorter nul terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

regarding statements like:

```
fwrite(cpy_buff, 1,sizeof(cpy_buff),dst);
```

This will write the whole buffer, even though most of the trailing bytes of the buffer `cpy_buff` are garbage.  Suggest:

```
fwrite(cpy_buff, 1,strlen(cpy_buff),dst);
```

Comment: Yes.You are right about strlen.This solved my problem.